# How to make method for multiple onClick()?

Tags: java, android

My android app has three buttons On click all the button do the same work,
And the code is so long I don't want to copy the code 3 time.
So, how can I do this using a method? 
This the code of one button

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.Btn1:

                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1); //Gallery acessing
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImage); //Onresult redarct to anothr activity
    }
    Uri photoUri = data.getData();
    if (photoUri != null) {
        try {
            currentImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
            selectedImage.setImageBitmap(currentImage);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent); //switch activity
             }
    }}

    }
```

Comment: I'm only seeing a switch case for 1 button

Comment: this is only for one button @DylanBurton #sir

Comment: 3 buttons that all do the same thing? Then just keep 1 button.

Comment: do you have the three buttons in the same activity?

Comment: @m0skit0 all 3 buttons do the same work but the purpose is different

Comment: @pablobu yes Sir Thay are

Comment: Then @Rafael T answer is correct, you just need to add the same onClickListener to the three buttons when creating your activity.

Comment: @pablobu answer of #Godfather work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code. I have created a public method doSomething() which is called on each button click so it performs the same function whenever it is called.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.Btn1:
                doSomething();
                break;
            case R.id.Btn2:
                doSomething();
                break;
        }
    }

public void doSomething(){
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1); //Gallery acessing
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImage); //Onresult redarct to anothr activity
    }
    Uri photoUri = data.getData();
    if (photoUri != null) {
        try {
            currentImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
            selectedImage.setImageBitmap(currentImage);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent); //switch activity
             }
    }}

    }
```

Comment: i got my answer but this will help someone else

Answer (score 2):

```
private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        //do all the work here
    }
}
```

then set it in you Views

```
view1.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
view2.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
//... etc
```

Comment: can you explain your answer please

Comment: there is really nothing to explain: You create a Listener as member and you set it to any View you like. It gets called on any view's click where you set it. since you only created one, everyt time you click, the same code gets executed

Comment: @krishna A Button is a View, so Any View.OnClickListener will work on Buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [performClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performClick()) of first button in other views click.

```
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.Btn1)
case R.id.Btn2:
 button1.performClick()
```

Comment: Yes its similar to you clicked button 1 .

Comment: The listener should be reused instead of performing a click on another button, this approach force you to rely on another button. What happens if button1 is removed later?

Comment: this help me with less time save my time and the time is money Thanx @Godfather